# Java HashMap for in-order data access

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a Java application and facing a producer consumer problem, and making use of HashMap to make sure the consumer is reading data in correct order. however i am not sure if this is an efficient approach:

Program A and Program B are different processes and communicating using Socket connection. Program B spawns Thread T. Program A keeps sending binary data to Program B through socket connection. program A recieves the binary data and puts into a list. Meanwhile,thread(T) will read the data one by one from the list.

Each data is associated with an order id(1,2,3,4,5), Thread T is supposed to read data with the same order. ex, it can not read data with order id 3 before 2. The problem is that Program A may not send data with correct order.

I choose hashmap to store the data, key is the order id, and value is the binary data. Thread T has a private counter, and keeps read data like this:

```
counter=1
while(stop)
  synchronize(mutexobj){
      if(!hashmap.containsKey(counter))
           wait();
      hashmap.get(counter++)
  }
```

In this way thread T will block until there is data availalbe in the hashmap with previous order id+1

However my question is that, is HashMap the best datastructure for this problem? I can not use normal array because i do not know how many data will be sent by program A.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways of solving this and yours should definitely work. You have one major issue though: you need to loop your if-statement.

If you for some reason get woken up prematurely from your `wait()` you will continue even if the map does not yet contain the value you're waiting for.

```
while(stop) {
  synchronized(mutexobj) {
    while(!hashmap.containsKey(counter)) {
      wait();
    }
    hashmap.get(counter++);
  }
}
```

I'd probably do something else entirely though, since I don't like messing with wait/notify directly.

My solution would probably be to keep an ordered cache of all incoming messages in the receiver that isn't the next in order and then push everything that is in sequence to a LinkedBlockingDeque and just have your consumer wait on the queue.

```
// Receiver
TreeSet<Message> cache = new TreeSet<>(new OrderMessagesByIndexComparator());
Message message;
while(run) {
  message = receive();
  cache.add(message);
  Iterator<Message> it = cache.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()) {
    Message m = it.next();
    if(m.index == next) {
      next++;
      it.remove();
      queue.add(m);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Message consumer
while(run) {
  message = queue.take();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! another question is, is it good to use hashtable whenever i want fast lookup? Actually in my program, the key is not only order id, but an warpper object which contains order id along with three other strings which together are like compound key in database. is hashtable good for that senario? Assuming i have a perfect hash code function, is there anything else i need to be careful of hashmap?

Comment: +1 for using a buffer but why leave the buffer as a map? Tree set will degrade your performance from constant to log.

Comment: @SophiaWeng: You generally don't need to worry about hashtable/map performance. Hash collisions will occur and as long as you don't mess too much with the growth parameters of the map you won't notice if a lookup returns immediately or have to pick between 2-3 objects with the same (truncated) hash.

@MateuszDymczyk: I think the loop becomes easier to follow. I guess you could just to it with something like `while(cache.containsKey(next)) { ... }` instead if you really want the O(1) performance for the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a queue data structure? You can insert from one end and removed from the other. A blocking queue might be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: i cant use queue because process A may not be sending data in sequence order,therefore thread T can read data in sequence order from the queue

Answer (score 0):

[DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) is similar to what you want, except that it is time oriented. A custom blocking queue that is ordered by a sequence id would follow a similar implementation pattern. If optimized, the O(lg n) priority queue could be replaced with an O(1) ring buffer since the sequence is deterministic. This would provide a reusable abstraction, perhaps named a `SequencedBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

I would adapt Actor model to approach this problem rather than worry about synchronizations and blocking. When actors receive a message, they can grab a thread and check whether the message is in order or not. If not then store somewhere for later use.